# Multi Thread Socket Server - clients talking to each other

Tags: java, c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, server

I have a question that is killing me and would like to share with you, maybe someone has the answer or a way to go to solve this question.

I have a good experience with Web development / Desktop API / REST connections and Socket. But all these connections even in a multi threaded server (regardless of the programming language) always worked with the client connecting to the server, requesting or sending something, the server responds and if is no longer needed terminates the connection. It turns out that I've been taking a look at online games (MMO RPG) and got my doubt, as a client connected to the server how I can see the other Client, interact, etc ...

I imagine keeping a list of all clients connected to the server each with its handle, so far so good, but how is it that I can see each connected doing something different? It means that every second so to speak as I get the client's server list of active clients and all status all that time? In my head it seems a little heavy if thinking of many users.

Imagine you are playing an online game and suddenly appears a new player and walks, runs, strikes, jumps, rolls all u are seeing, hence comes another, and another, do I get a massive package of data telling me each user connected and what they are doing or am I thinking the wrong side about the problem and the thing is simpler?

Already I appreciate the answers :)

Comment: tip: google socket.io

Comment: How often is the update?  You'll find that the updates are a little more periodic and localized than they look.

Answer (score 1):

In your example it would me more efficient communication-wise for the server to map your game state into server memory. From there on it can map all connected players into your state and send a single integrated state update to you instead of connection all these players to your client. Of course, a lot of different scenario's are possible. Just merging all extra players into a single communication message and sending that out (without mapping your state itself) is another option. In general, the server would only have to send a single merged user input for all connected players once new players are connected to your game.

Comment: I saw an article that explains a bit of it. Like they map the game in zones, so if I'm in zone 1, and there's more players in the same zone the server sends a packet to each client with all the players states in that zone. It sounds a bit heavy in my head I think, but i can't think of any other solution

Comment: @Steffano - The server doesn't even have to send detailed information about all players in the zone to you - that's only needed for players in your _field of view_, which is usually much smaller.